# PHP all commands are extremely slow

Tags: php, performance, time, centos

Can anybody please tell me if WTF is going on with my PHP or where can I find some logs with more information?

Running the simplest command takes about a minute!!!! I can't handle that emotionally :)

time php -v

```
PHP 7.3.31 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2021 10:24:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.31, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

real    0m45.016s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Running without configuration is better, but also to slow:
time php -n -v

```
PHP 7.3.31 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2021 10:24:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.31, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

real    0m6.010s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Thank you all for helping! Have a great day!

Comment: If you don't have an extraordinarily high load on the system, I'd edit the `php.ini` and disable all extensions. If that fixes the issue, then you can re-enable one at a time to find the problem.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the fast reply!  I'll try that :)